# matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A(A-I_3)^2=0$ . what form can $A$ take .

I hope that someone will see my solution

My solution :

First we can see that $X^3-2X^2+X$ vanish $A$ and its degree is $3$ so it's the characteristic polynomial of $A$ , we use theorem of cayley hamilton :$\mathbb{R}^3=ker(A)\oplus ker((A-I_3)^2)$ , so $rank(A)+rank((A-I_3)^2)=3$.
we have also $Ker((A-I_3)^2)\subseteq Ker(A)$ .than $rank(A) \le rank((A-I_3)^2)$ we deduce that $Rank(A) \le 1$ , so either $A=0$ either $Rank(A)=1$ , from the charcteristic polynomial of A we can see that $Tr(A)=2$ than $A$ is similar to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ , reciproqually the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ doesn't verifie $A(A-I_3)^2=0$ so the only solution is $A=0$

Is this correct please ?

Comment: This is not correct, since obviously $A=I_3$ is also a solution.

Comment: I guess I took the wrong matrix , maybe this should work :\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Why is $Ker((A-I_3)^2) \subseteq Ker(A)$?

Comment: sorry my fault $Im((A-I_3)^2)\subseteq Ker(A) $ I guess I didn't wake up well , I should repeat everything

Comment: well we'll have to wait for someone to answer this

Comment: we can also work with a basis related to this direct sum \mathbb{R}^3=ker(A)\oplus ker((A-I_3)^2)

Comment: Hint: use the fact that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x(x-1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is $P\in GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $A=PUP^{-1}$ where $U$ is as follows

Case 1. $A$ is diagonalizable. $U=diag(a,b,c)$.

Case 2. $A$ is not diagonalizable. $U=diag(a,\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix})$.

where $a,b,c\in \{0,1\}$.

EDIT. @ Florentin , if you don't know the Jordan form, you can use your formula

$\mathbb{R}^3=ker(A)\oplus ker((A-I_3)^2)$

and proceed as follows:

Case 1. $dim(\ker(A))=0$. Then $(A-I_3)^2=0_3$.

Case 2. $dim(\ker(A))=1$. Then $A\sim diag(0,B)$ where $(B-I_2)^2=0_2$.

Case 3. $dim(\ker(A))=2$. Then $A\sim diag(0,0,1)$.

Case 4. $dim(\ker(A))=3$. Then $A=0_3$.

Comment: you used jordan form?

Comment: @ Florentin , yes, I did.

Comment: case 3 , I guess $A\sim diag(0,1,1)$

Comment: No, $A\sim diag(0,1,1)$ is a part of Case 2.

Comment: Ah oui , merci beaucoup